# JpaRepository + Hibernate + OneToMany вылетает LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

реализую отношение one-to-many по [этому туториалу](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/) а также [этому спринговому туториалу](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/). Я НЕ использую сессии и прочий hibernate напрямую, я использую JpaRepository и аннотации JPA. Есть объекты Owner (one) & Book (many):

первая таблица:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "owners")
public class Owner implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "owner_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "owner_name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "owner")
    private Set<Book> books= new HashSet<>(0);

    public Worker() {
    }
}
```

вторая таблица:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "book_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "book_name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
    private Owner owner;

    public Task() {
    }
}
```

слой репозиториев стандартный, без реализации:

```
public  interface OwnerRepository extends JpaRepository<Owner,Long> {}

public  interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book,Long> {}
```

Owner service: (book service такой же)

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class OwnerServiceImpl implements OwnerService {

    @Autowired
    private OwnerRepository ownerRepository;

    @Override
    public Owner create(Owner owner) {return ownerRepository.save(owner);}

    @Override
    public Owner read(Long id) {return ownerRepository.findOne(id);}

    @Override
    public List<Owner> readAll() {return ownerRepository.findAll();}

    @Override
    public void delete(Owner owner) {ownerRepository.delete(owner);}

}
```

Создав два класса service, я захотел протестить их. Создал несколько Owner,Book ну и пытаюсь связать их как указано [здесь](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/), т.е. добавляю в объектe Owner в Set новую книжку, а в объект Book обновляю ссылку на Owner. Сохраняю в репозиторий сначала Owner, затем Book. Затем пытаюсь прочитать Owner из репозитория, а во время обращения к полю выдаёт

> unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception.

может я вообще неправильно работаю с репозиторием и JPA? как нужно сохранять/обновлять ссылки в сущностях?

**===UPDATE===**

мне кажется я решил проблему, использовав @NamedEntityGraph & @EntityGraph.
Я аннотировал Owner

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Owner.books",
    attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("books"))
```

Но в интерфейсе репозитория пришлось переопределить стандартные методы:

```
@Override
@EntityGraph(value = "Owner.books", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
List<Owner> findAll();


@Override
@EntityGraph(value = "Owner.books", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
OwnerfindOne(Long aLong);
```

Тоже самое сделал с Book. Когда я делаю запрос из репозитория Owner на считывание объекта, всё загружается нормально - ссылки в Set ссылаются на объекты Book. 
Но когда я делаю запрос к Book репозиторию - объект Book имеет ссылку на Owner, НО в этом внутреннем Owner ссылки на дополнительные книги бросают LazyInitException. Почему? ссылки просматриваю в Idea на брек поинте.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, через дебаггер (или любым иным способом) сообщения всего стека исключений. Из этого сообщения сложно что-то вывести.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

У вас стоит `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` это значит, что хибернейт не будет инициализировать эти поля пока вы к ним не обратитесь. Но т.к. вы обращаетесь к этим полям за пределами транзакционных методов, он не может это сделать и выкидывает ошибку.

Чтобы этого избежать надо, что метод, который обращается к этим полям был с аннотацей [Transactional](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html). В вашем случае это `EntitiesServicesTest.ooops()`.

Либо можно немного изменить реализацию OwnerServiceImpl.read(). Сделать такое:

```
@Override
public Owner read(Long id) {
    Owner owner = ownerRepository.findOne(id);
    owner.getBooks().iterator();
    return owner;
}
```

Или как предложили в комментариях: `Hibernate.initialize(owner.getBooks());`

Это хак, но он заставит хибернейт инициировать коллекцию. НО! Возможно это не всегда надо и тогда надо выбрать первый вариант и отталкиваться от здравого смысла, смотреть, где надо навешивать аннотацию, а где нет.

Comment: У меня аннотирован весь класс сервиса.

Comment: @arg Я не про класс, который возвращает объект, а там где вы к нему обращаетесь. Т.е. там где вызываете Book.getOwner() или Owner.getBooks()

Comment: ясно. А как надо обращаться к полям?

Comment: @arg Нет. Надо повесить транзакшионал там где вы обращаетесь к понял. ЕСЛИ это возможно и не противоречит архитектуре. Либо же модно обратиться к полям которые вам нужно до того как вернуть объект. Сейчас обновлю ответ.

Comment: я повесил Transactional на свой тестовый метод, LazyInitException падать перестал, к полю обратился нормально, но после работы тестового метода база данных оказалась пустой.

Comment: @arg Вы видимо что-то делаете с этим полем? Очищаете или изменяете. Все изменения которые происходят в транзакшионал методах сохраняются в БД(если объект привязан к некой сущность БД, конечно, как в вашем случае).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30624/discussion-between-arg-and-vartlok).

Comment: извините , тут похоже ограничение на сообщения в комментариях. вот чат есть )

Comment: Вместо итератора можно использовать `Hibernate.initialize(owner.getBooks());` если сервис @Transactional

Answer (score 1):

Стоит также упомянуть, что fetch type по дефолту как раз LAZY.
Я для решения проблемы поставил `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` и всё заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Может кому будет полезно,при помощи JOIN FETCH директивы,в интерфейсе BookRepository добавить например такой метод

```
public  interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book,Long> {

       @Query(value = "select b from Book b join fetch b.owners")
        List<Book> lazyLoad();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eager будет подтягивать твои коллекции всегда,когда ты обращаешься к сущности,даже если тебе эти коллекции не нужны.После этого хибернейт будет следить за их состоянием - что тоже не беслпатно.Если коллекции не большие - то можно оставить Eager

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего будет сделать однонавравленую ManyToOne на стороне Book и делать выборку книг запросом JPQL

```
 public  interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book,Long> {
    
           @Query(value = "select b from Book b where b.owner_id = :id")
            List<Book> getBooks(@Param("id") Long id);
    
    }
```